# Query for user access to application modules

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have to create a query that will be returning the users and the application modules they have access for. Along with the list of users and modules the query should also return if any module is not accessible for that user.

The 'ApplicationUsers' table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #ApplicationUsers
(
userId INT,
UserName VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO #ApplicationUsers VALUES
(1, 'Daniel'), (2,'Martin'), (3, 'Brandon'), (4, 'Doug')
```

The 'ApplicationModule' table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #ApplicationModules
(
moduleId INT,
moduleName VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO #ApplicationModules VALUES
(1, 'Sales'), (2, 'Production'), (3, 'Marketing')
```

This is how we store module access for users in 'ModuleAccess' table:

```
CREATE TABLE #ModuleAccess
(
Id INT,
userId INT,
moduleId INT
)
INSERT INTO #ModuleAccess VALUES
(1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 3), (3, 2, 1), (4, 2, 2), (5, 3, 2)
```

In the example above 'Daniel' can access only 'Sales' and 'Marketing', 'Martin' can access 'Sales' and 'Production' and so on. So the required output is:

```
CREATE TABLE #ExampleOutput
(
[userName] VARCHAR(50),
[Sales] VARCHAR(5),
[Production] VARCHAR(5),
[Marketing] VARCHAR(5)
)
INSERT INTO #ExampleOutput VALUES 
('Daniel', 'true', 'false', 'true'),
('Martin', 'true', 'true', 'false'),
('Brandon', 'false', 'true', 'false'),
('Doug', 'false', 'false', 'false')

SELECT * FROM #ExampleOutput
```

I used pivot query but there are a couple of limitations in it(may be I am making mistakes in it). First, the pivot columns are static whereas I need dynamic column names(Application Modules). Second, I need to include all the users with all the modules with access or without access that I am unable to achieve. Can someone write a sample query to help me how this can be done?

Comment: Do you have the flexibility to change the table structure of #ModuleAccess?

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with the table design as outlined in the question this will work.

```
(SELECT username, am.moduleName AS Module, CAST(0 AS BIT) AS HasAccess
FROM #ApplicationUsers AS au INNER JOIN #ApplicationModules AS am ON 1 = 1
EXCEPT
SELECT username, am.moduleName AS Module, CAST(0 AS BIT) AS HasAccess
FROM #ApplicationUsers AS au INNER JOIN #ModuleAccess AS ma ON ma.userId = au.userId INNER JOIN #ApplicationModules AS am ON am.moduleId = ma.moduleId)
UNION 
SELECT username, am.moduleName AS Module, CAST(1 AS BIT) AS HasAccess
FROM #ApplicationUsers AS au INNER JOIN #ModuleAccess AS ma ON ma.userId = au.userId INNER JOIN #ApplicationModules AS am ON am.moduleId = ma.moduleId
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Though with the cartesian join "1 = 1" not a wonderful solution.  If you are able to I would modify the ModuleAccess table and include a "HasAccess BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)" column, and have the application include all Modules for a new user.  If the user doesn't have access then set the new column to be a zero, if they do have access then set it to a one.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I can not make any changes to the table schema but I have created a working query. I am adding it as an answer if someone else need it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working query if someone has a similar requirement:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',', '') + QUOTENAME([moduleName])
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [moduleName]
        FROM #ApplicationModules
        ) AS ApplicationModules

    SET @DynamicPivotQuery = '
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT D.[moduleId], D.[moduleName], U.[UserName] AS [User] FROM 
#ApplicationUsers U
LEFT OUTER JOIN #ModuleAccess DA
ON U.[userId] = DA.[userId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN #ApplicationModules D
ON D.[moduleId] = DA.[moduleId]
) A
pivot (MIN(moduleId)for [moduleName] in (' + @ColumnName + ')) as [moduleIdId]
'

    EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery

    DROP TABLE #ApplicationUsers
    DROP TABLE #ModuleAccess
    DROP TABLE #ApplicationModules
```